# Encoding json which contains arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm currently putting a Json file together in PHP as below

```
function createJson($eventIds, $TipsTB, $TipsTW) {

    $jsonData = new stdClass();

    $jsonData->source = "Betting Tips";
    $jsonData->published = date('Y-m-d H:s:i;');
    $jsonData->status = true;
    $jsonData->eventIDs = $eventIds;
    $jsonData->TipsTB = $TipsTB;
    $jsonData->TipsTW = $TipsTW;

    return $jsonData;
}
```

`$eventIDs`, `$TipsTB` and `$TipsTW` are all arrays. The first containing number strings the second two containing text strings.

When I return from the function and use

```
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

I get

```
{"source":"Betting Tips","published":"2015-05-18 18:54:22;","status":true,"eventIDs":[],"TipsTB":[]}
```

and not a list of what is inside the brackets of the array. Has the data in the array been appended or is there a different function do do that.?

Thanks muchas...

Comment: According to your output, they ARE arrays, but the arrays are empty.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($eventIds);` to see if the array contains what you expect.

Comment: Noob mistake, It was the scope of the arrays that I had confused. They were indeed empty.

Comment: PHP note: if all you're doing is passing in values so you can serialize them, [pass them by reference](https://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead of as copies, using `createJson(&$eventIds, &$TipsTB, &$TipsTW)`

Comment: Cool thx 'Pomax' I did not know you could do that....